# how to make window in focus in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I was wondering if it's possible to make a script where it brings one specific application in focus every 12 min and then minimizes it instantly.

So to summarize:

- wait 12 minutes
- bring app to focus
- minimize it (or make it re-focus last used app if possible?)

So far i only found that minimizing it will make the previous app come in focus again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is definitely something you can do in AutoHotkey. The links below are to the AutoHotkey help document for the specific items you mentioned.

- wait 12 minutes:

You have at least a couple options for this. You could use a combination of `Loop` and `Sleep` or `SetTimer` by itself. I'd recommend `SetTimer` but familiarizing yourself with the other two is beneficial as well.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm

- bring app to focus
- minimize it (or make it re-focus last used app if possible?)

There are a lot of window commands in AutoHotkey. These two are for what you specifically asked:

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm

Depending on why you need to have a window focused, there may be a different way of accomplishing what you need. If you need to type something in a certain window every 12 min., you could also use `ControlSend` without having to activate it.

Here is an example to get you started:

```
f1:: ; f1 will toggle your script to run
bT := !bT ; this is the toggle variable
If bT
{
    GoSub , lTimer ; triggers the timer sub to run immediately since SetTimer has to wait for period to expire on first run
    SetTimer , lTimer , 2500 ; this is in milliseconds, 12min = 720000ms
}
Else
    SetTimer , lTimer , Off
Return

lTimer: ; timer sub
If WinExist( "EEHotkeys" ) ; change EEHotkeys to be the name of your window in all places shown
{
    WinActivate , EEHotkeys
    WinWaitActive , EEHotkeys
    WinMinimize , EEHotkeys
}
Return
```

**EDIT:** As suggested by samthecodingman in the comments, you could alternatively get the active window's title, activate your window, then reactivate the original window.

```
lTimer: ; timer sub
If WinExist( "EEHotkeys" ) ; change EEHotkeys to be the name of your window in all places shown
{
    WinGetActiveTitle , sActiveWindow
    WinActivate , EEHotkeys
    WinWaitActive , EEHotkeys
    WinActivate , %sActiveWindow%
}
Return
```

Comment: You might also want to add the second part of the question to your answer. (i.e. get the current window, focus/activate the desired app, and then return focus back to the original window, rather than minimizing the focussed app)